# How to specify a DependencyProperty as a resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to create buttons programmatically in WPF which grows to a specific size when `IsMouseOver == true`, and shrink to its original size when `IsMouseOver == false`.

To achieve this behaviour, I derived the `Button` class, and added a `DependencyProperty`:

```cpp
public class ScalableButton : Button
{
    public Storyboard MouseOutAnimation
    {
        get { return (Storyboard)GetValue(MouseOutAnimationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MouseOutAnimationProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MouseOutAnimation.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOutAnimationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MouseOutAnimation", typeof(Storyboard), typeof(ScalableButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public ScalableButton(double originalScale, Style style)
        : base()
    {
        CreateMouseOutAnimation(originalScale);
        RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(originalScale, 1, 0.5, 0.5);
        RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        Style = style;
        ApplyTemplate();
    }

    private void CreateMouseOutAnimation(double originalScale)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animX = new DoubleAnimation();
        animX.To = originalScale;
        animX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        DoubleAnimation animY = new DoubleAnimation();
        animY.To = 1;
        animY.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(animX);
        sb.Children.Add(animY);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, this.RenderTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animX, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animY, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty));
        MouseOutAnimation = sb;
    }
}
```

Then, I created a `Style` with a `ControlTemplate` to make a custom appearance for my buttons, and added a `Storyboard` resource to scale up them, and another to scale down and here is the problem:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type rgw:ScalableButton}" x:Key="EllipseWithText" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type rgw:ScalableButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY" To="1.2" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation">
                        <!-- This would be the one which scales down -->
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid" RenderTransform="{TemplateBinding RenderTransform}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonEllipse" Height="50" Width="150" Fill="#00000000" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonText" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOutAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So, how can I specify the `ScalableButton.MouseOutAnimation` as a resource?

Or is there any other way the achieve the scalable button?

Comment: I don't understand your problem... what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Will `originalScale` ever differ from 1.0? How does your `MouseOverAnimation` take that into account?

Comment: Why derive from `Button` at all? Why not just do all this in a custom template instead?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: This code now doesn't scale down my buttons, as I couldn't bind the `MouseOutAnimation` to `ScalableButton.MouseOutAnimation`, that's my question.
@Clemens: yes, originalScale can be less then 1.0, but it doesn't really affect `MouseOverAnimation` as it grows from the actual scale to 1.2.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: I can't bind anything to the Storyboards I define in `ControlTemplate.Resources`, it gives an error about the storyboards not being freezeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a derived Button.

Do not set the `To` property in the ExitActions animations. This will automatically animate from the current property values back to the original property values. Note that in the example below i initiallly set `ScaleX = 0.5`.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" ScaleX="0.5"/>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Ellipse Height="50" Width="150" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" />
                    <TextBlock Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                        To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                        To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT:
Although `MinWidth` is certainly not a scale factor: you could bind like the following.

```
<ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding MinWidth,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's almost perfect! When ScaleX is set initially, it works perfectly, however, when I try to bind something to it, it doesn't apply, it stays at 1.0. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I use the `MinWidth` property to set the initial `ScaleX` (`ScaleX="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"`).  Any ideas?

Comment: You could of course also follow your original approach and bind the Grid's RenderTransform to the Button's RenderTransform by TemplateBinding. But then you have to make sure that RenderTransform always contains a ScaleTransform.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much! I'm still learning WPF, and this problem haunted me for two weeks now... so I'm really grateful!  Yes, I know that using `MinWidth` is kind of a hack, but now that I know how to do it, I can modify it to a more proper way. Thank you again!